# .Load strange behaviors with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I load a part of my checkout basket inside an HTML that works as a dropdown. this works on all browsers.

I then bind the buy button to update the basket when pressing the button - an click that wont refresh the page. This works in all browser except IE- but if i refresh the page in IE it refreshes the basket from my first script.

I then have a basket that shows the added product. However - If i then try to add another product - it suddenly replaces the basket with an added product to an empty basket. How is this possible, since the basket do have products - I can see that if I navigate to it.

Script to load the basket from start:

```
$('ul.acdropdownfull').load('/m4n?seid=etailer-basket div#centerbox.itembox.centerbox');
```

Refresh the basket at click:

```
$(".actionbutton").click(function(){
$('ul.acdropdownfull div#centerbox.itembox.centerbox .body').load('/m4n?seid=etailer-basket div#centerbox.itembox.centerbox .body');
});
```

I also clear the cache by:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Lastly - i tried to set a timeout function with different times:

```
setTimeout( function(){
$(".addinfo .actionbutton").click(function(){
$('.actionbutton div#centerbox.itembox.centerbox .body').load('/m4n?seid=etailer-basket div#centerbox.itembox.centerbox .body');
});
}, 100);
```

Comment: What is .actionbutton? is it an Anchor? If yes, you need to do preventDefault

Comment: Its an a href element - a button that adds a product to the basket.

Comment: try this $(".actionbutton").click(function(e ){ e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();